# C# HTML Class Library?

Tags: c#, html

I'm looking for a class library or namespace that pretty fully represents the [HTML 4.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4) or [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) specification.  Does anybody know of anything like this?  System.Web.UI looked promising at a glance, but I'm not seeing what I'm looking for there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many thing you can find out on codeplex

like

HTML Agility pack

System.HTML

Answer (score 7):

You might want to have a look at the

> **[Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)**